# iOS app development on windows 10 64-bit

Tags: ios, windows, ide

I need to build a very simple app for iOS phone but after searching the IDEs for iOS phone development i found that one way to do we will need to install VMWare with OSX image.

Now I am not sure it could be the ultimate solution and i hope there could be some other way to develop apps for iOS with.

Please suggest me some lightweight IDE that could be able to run over windows OS...
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use VMWare to develop iOS application.

Install [Hackintosh](http://www.hackintosh.com/)

or

In windows, you can use [Xamarin](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/) or [VisualStudio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn771552.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you have core2Duo Processor you can install iAtkos.

http://iatkos.me/